onAppear not called after sheet dismissal
Have the following problem here. I have a root view and some action happens that triggers a sheet to be shown. When the sheet is dismissed the root view's onAppear isn't called.
Example:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var toggle: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("\(toggle ? "Hide" : "Show")") {
            toggle.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $toggle) {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("body.onAppear")
        }
    }
}


What I have read and searched is for me to use onDismiss for the sheet but I want the action to be view specific not sheet dismissal specific as the sheet can be opened from many places across the app.

Why is "can be opened from many places across the app" a reason for not using onDismiss? You would still be using multiple sheet modifiers (if you are not then you are probably doing something wrong). Just pass an additional onDimiss argument to the desired sheet modifier.

In your case the root view does not disappear when the sheet is displayed, so it does not (re) appear. You should use the onDismiss closure parameter of the sheet.

you could add a specific id to the view, eg add .id(toggle) after .onAppear

as far as I know onAppear only gets called once when the view is added to the view hierarchy. What you're looking for is probably the onChange modifier https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-run-some-code-when-state-changes-using-onchange

Not sure why this has been downvoted; using the .onChange modifier to test the toggle is false would do the just to indicate that the sheet has been dismissed.
